# How to list ingredients for a product if one product can have another product as ingredient

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok, so here is my simple table, `P1-P4 = Product`, `Ix = Ingredient`

```
+---------------------+
|   A    B    C    D  |
+---------------------+
| 1 P1   I1   I2   I3 |
| 2 P2   I4   I5   I6 |
| 3 P3   I7   I8   P4 |
| 4 P4   I10  I11     |
+---------------------+
```

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is, that I can list all Ingredients for example for P3 so I will get a list that looks like that

```
I7
I8
I10
I11
```

Is that even possible via a formula in Excel without using VBA?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `=VLOOKUP("P3",$A$1:$D$4,2,FALSE)` To get first ingrediant, change the 2 to a 3 to get the second.  You can use cell references to make it more dynamic.

Comment: Looks to me you need to unpivot the data.  which can be done [Example on other stack site](http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)  or does this Have to be a formula?  Though why is 10 and 11 in your list if you're only looking for P3? Link does have a "Formula only" response too.

Comment: I'm very aware of `VLOOKUP`, but I need one formula for one cell, for example in `D5`, where I want to list all ingredients for `P3`

Comment: @xQbert - P4 is an ingredient in P3: I10 and I11 are the P4 ingredients...

Comment: @TimWilliams ah missed that.  wow... this could have recursion in it too... don't think unpivot alone will do it then.  I personally can't think of a way to handle this formula only.

Comment: I think you're going to need to use VBA for this if there could be multiple levels of nesting of ingredients.

Comment: Atm I'm using `E1=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(INDIRECT(Constants!$A$6),0,3,1,3))` to list the ingredients, but with this I only get `I7 I8 P4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive UDF that does what you want.  I do not believe that a formula will do it.

```
Dim cnt as long

Function viceversa(lkup As Variant, rng As Range, nmbr As Long, Optional rec As Boolean) As String
Dim rngArr
Dim temp as string
If rec = False Then cnt = 1

rngArr = rng.Value
For i = LBound(rngArr, 1) To UBound(rngArr, 1)
    If rngArr(i, 1) = lkup Then
        For j = LBound(rngArr, 2) + 1 To UBound(rngArr, 2)
            If Left(rngArr(i, j), 1) <> "P" Then
                If cnt = nmbr Then
                    viceversa = rngArr(i, j)
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                End If
            Else
                temp = viceversa(rngArr(i, j), rng, nmbr, True)
                If temp <> "" Then
                    viceversa = temp
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
viceversa = ""

End Function
```

Put this in in a module attached to the workbook. `cnt is a public variable and the`Dim cnt as Long` needs to be at the top of the module.

Then you can call it like this:

```
=viceversa($A$3,$A$1:$D$4,1)
```

$A$3 is the Product, $A$1:$D$4 is the Range including the first column of products. `1` is the first ingredient.  I used a helper column with numbers:

[image]

It does not matter if you have 1 or more products as ingredients it will continue till all are accounted for.

**Note**

One thing that will need to change is the test of whether it is a product or not.  So change this line `If Left(rngArr(i, j), 1) <> "P" Then` to something that works to denote that the ingredient being tested is actually a product.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it when I'm back home